# javax.servlet.ServletException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: char[]

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, maxlength

I want to validate a form input. Specifically a `name` parameter which has a maximum length of 255 characters. But I get this exception

```
UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length validating type char[]. Check configuration for ...
```

for the following mapping:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/savename")
    public Response saveName(
            @Length(max = 255)
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) char[] name
    ) {
        return ...
    }

}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`@Length`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.html) works with `String`s only. For character arrays use [`@Size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) instead. Here's the correct mapping:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/savename")
    public Response saveName(
            @Size(max = 255)
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) char[] name
    ) {
        return ...
    }

}
```